# When are arguments assigned for synchronised methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I cannot remember when arguments are assigned when calling `synchronized` methods.

```
public int methodA() { return ... }

public synchronized void methodB(int arg) {}
```

When calling methodB from multiple threads

```
methodB(methodA());
```

I know that the threads are blocked until previous thread finished running methodB.
My question is when arg is assigned? (or say when methodA() is called?).
Is it before or after the blocking happens?

Comment: @JiaLi Please ensure your code compiles before posting.

Comment: @BeUndead It is specified. It's equivalent to wrapping the method body in a `synchronized (this) { ... }` block.

Comment: `methodA()` is called before blocking. Otherwise, `methodA()` would behave as if it were `synchronized` as well. The way you should think of it is as if you invoked `methodA()` and assigned its return value to a local variable, which you then passed to `methodB`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I was leaving some leniency for a case where the method result isn't used in the method, and has no impact on the system - I don't know if the language specifies that the call to `methodA()` must execute at all.  For example, if it just `return null`s, I don't know if that gets inlined.

Comment: @BeUndead: well if optimization is relevant the VM has lock-coarsening as an optimization option, which complicates things probably. Not seeing how optimizing away methodA changes things though.

Answer (score 4):

MethodA executes first. The intrinsic lock on the object that methodB is called on isn’t acquired until the executing thread tries to enter methodB.

This is in the JLS, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1

> A synchronized method (§8.4.3.6) automatically performs a lock action when it is invoked; its body is not executed until the lock action has successfully completed. If the method is an instance method, it locks the monitor associated with the instance for which it was invoked (that is, the object that will be known as this during execution of the body of the method). If the method is static, it locks the monitor associated with the Class object that represents the class in which the method is defined. If execution of the method's body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor.

The JLS says the lock is acquired when the method is invoked. MethodB doesn’t get invoked until methodA has already completed and provided a return value.